# Splitting a treap at a key that exists inside the tree

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I'm been trying to implement and understand the `split/merge` operations on a `treap`. Every node has two keys: a heap key and a tree key. Looking at the heap keys you should see a valid heap and same with the tree keys.

Splitting a treap is easier than normal because you can just insert a dummy node with the maxmimum or minimum priority (depends on if it's a max-heap or min-heap). However, [this link](http://pavpanchekha.com/blog/treap.html#sec-5-3) just says to assume that the splitting key isn't in the tree. However, what if I always want existing key inside the right tree, or the left tree? What do I do?

Comment: This is unclear. Suppose the key in question is in the left subtreap. What are the requirements of the split?

Comment: If the treap contains `[1,2,3,4]` and we want to split the treap at `2`, the two resulting treaps would contain `[1,2]` and `[3,4]`. The page I read said the node you split at should not be contained in the treap, but what if I want to split the treap at a node that is contained?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Find the node with the key in question.

   Move it up to become the new root (by giving it a very high -- or very low -- priority).

   Split off the left (or right) subtree.